# Return Не работает с метками

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

```
r@ print("Продолжить (y/n): ")
yesorno = readLine()!!
when (yesorno) {
    "y" -> return main()
    "n" -> return
    else -> {
        print("ERRRRRROOOOOOOOR#4734")
        return@r
    }
}
```

Не работает return@r (unresolved reference @r)

Comment: Как оно должно работать?

Comment: возвращаться к метке "r"

Comment: Для этого return должен быть внутри участка кода, отмеченного меткой. А здесь такого нет.

Comment: Не работает так

Comment: вы тут goto буквально сделать пытаетесь (которого нет в котлине и вообще goto - зло), только зачем? чем обычный цикл и break не устраивает? и что такое `return main()`? может return@main?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы при ошибке она заново запрашивала ввод переменной

Comment: В таких случаях как ваш обычно do-while цикл используют.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете использовать так "метки", вы вообще ничего не можете использовать так. Просто скакнуть по коду вообще во всех высокоуровневых языках программирования считается жесточайшим моветоном. Даже если вы пишете на каком-нибудь паскале, где есть оператор goto, делающий то что попытались сделать вы, не используйте его. Никогда. Вообще. Оставьте это ассемблеру

return завершает блок кода. Это может быть метод, лямбда, цикл, может еще что-то специфичное. Пример:

```
observer.filter {
    //do smth
    return@filter true //показываем что тут возвращается результат лямбды, а не той функции, в которой она описана
}


lbl@ for(i in 0..w)
        for(j in ){
            //do smth
            if(smth){
                continue@lbl// переходим к следующей итерации внешнего цикла
            }
        }
```